# Did anyone implement DirectTrack affiliate api?

Tags: php, api, affiliate, php-oara

Did anyone implement DirectTrack affiliate api? if yes which method gives proper subid/clickref with all other transaction details ?

Thankyou for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used following reporting url and found what i needed;

[Article](https://aff.onenetworkdirect.com/partners/reports/transaction.html?program_menu_type=0&program_id=0&period=this_month&start_date_day=%7Byyyy-MM-dd%7D&end_date_day=%7Byyyy-MM-dd%7D&status_id=0&report_type=csv)

Regards,
Zubair